# Convert array of Binary objects to strings in Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am using python-3.x, and I am trying to convert a list of a numpy array "Binary's" to decimal numbers, as I know I need to convert these Binary's first to Strings then I can convert them to Decimal ex:

**1.Binary** = 101011111 >>> **2.String**= '101011111' >>>>> **3.decimal**= 351

```
binary= '101011111'
binary = int(binary, 2)
print (binary)
```

But is there any way to convert a list of Binary's straightaway to decimal I don't want to convert them to Strings?

**1.Binary** = 101011111 >>> **2.decimal**= 351

```
My input is:
Type: int64
Size:(3, 8)
Value: array:([[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
               [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
               [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1]])

the output:  ([[152],
               [248],
               [157]])
```

Comment: binary? decimal? it's data _representation_. What's your input data?

Comment: What do you mean a "binary"? What is the `type`?

Comment: My input is: Type: int64 - Size:(3, 8) - Value: array ([[1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0], [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1]])

Comment: So I need to get another array contains the Value in decimal

Comment: So you have a `numpy` array? Can you please edit your post to include your actual input and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your binary numbers are built from arrays, each array position represents a certain base value (`2**n`) or a left shift (`<< n`). This, together with the broadcasting of `numpy`, allows a solution like:

```
binary = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]])

wordlength = binary.shape[1]
shift = np.arange(wordlength-1, -1, -1)

decimal = np.sum(binary << shift, 1)
```

Thus, I generate a simple range from `n-1` down to `0` which I then broadcast and use to shift each binary digit to get its value. Then I just sum up the values along the dimension of each binary number.